# Adding a pure "Force Constraint" between two objects

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Rigid body simulations in Blender have a "Motor" Rigid Body Constraint which can constraint the velocity by which two objects are attracted or repelled.

Is there a "Force" Rigid Body Constraint that when enabled would simply apply a force between the two participating objects? The reason I am after a force is because that is all I have at the moment and calculating the velocity that the force I want to apply between two specific points would cause is not exactly straightforward :/

Any ideas?